# How the URL-Rewrite will work with 3 Params aswell?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, front-controller

i have build a URL-Routing FrontController in PHP. All works fine, but now i find a error, if i have more params then 2 it dont works, for example:

This URL works:
  `"www.comelio.com/business-intelligence/anleser/"`

but this URL dont works: 
  `"www.comelio.com/business-intelligence/data-mining/anleser/"`

My Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?([\w-]+)/?([\w-]+)/?([\w-]+)? index.php?lang=$1&rubrik=$2&unterrubrik=$3&seite=$4
```

Here my Routing if-else code:

```
if($seite == null) {
  $filename = "{$rubrik}.html";
  $xdmvalue = $saxonProc->createAtomicValue($filename);
  $xsltProc->setParameter("articlePfad", $xdmvalue);

  if(in_array($filename, $filelist)) {
    $xmlFile = $dir . "/" . $filename;
    $xsltProc->setSourceFromFile($xmlFile);
  } else {
    echo "404";
  }
} else if(isset($seite) && isset($rubrik)){
  $filename = "{$rubrik}_{$seite}.html";
  $xdmvalue = $saxonProc->createAtomicValue($filename);
  $xsltProc->setParameter("articlePfad", $xdmvalue);

  if(in_array($filename, $filelist)) {
    $xmlFile = $dir . "/" . $filename;
    $xsltProc->setSourceFromFile($xmlFile);
  } else {
    echo "404";
  }
} else if(isset($seite) && isset($rubrik) && ($unterrubrik)){
  $filename = "{$rubrik}_{$unterrubrik}_{$seite}.html";
  $xdmvalue = $saxonProc->createAtomicValue($filename);
  $xsltProc->setParameter("articlePfad", $xdmvalue);

  if(in_array($filename, $filelist)) {
    $xmlFile = $dir . "/" . $filename;
    $xsltProc->setSourceFromFile($xmlFile);
  } else {
    echo "404";
  }
}
```

Before i write this code so the second parameter works only, now only the third parameter works, for example now works:
`"comelio.com/business-intelligence/data-mining/anleser"`

And this dont works: 
`"comelio.com/business-intelligence/anleser"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [htaccess Tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) here (Make sure to add http in the URL field).

In your Rewrite Condition, you only make the slashed optional. Thus, the rewriter will always split up the request url to match 4 parts. Try changing your rule to

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?([\w-]+)?/?([\w-]+)?/?([\w-]+)? index.php?lang=$1&rubrik=$2&unterrubrik=$3&seite=$4
```

(Note the question marks behind the `([\w-]+)`)

This will give you
`http://www.comelio.com/index.php?lang=business-intelligence%26rubrik=data-mining%26unterrubrik=anleser%26seite=`

and

`http://www.comelio.com/index.php?lang=business-intelligence%26rubrik=anleser%26unterrubrik=%26seite=`

Comment: This is right, but i need to have the "lang" param filled to 100%. WIth this RewriteRule it dont works

Comment: The only case where this is not filled is when you don't pass any params. Then its the empty string. If you need a special treatment there, you have to add an additional rule for zero parameters.